# Destructure to global

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this setup as a global:

```
var blah;
```

Now in a function I do this:

```
function() {
   var { blah } = obj;
}
```

However the global `blah` is not override with the destructure value. The desructurd value is available locally in that function. Is there anyway to get it out and global?

Comment: Maybe because of using `var`?

Comment: Use `({blah} = obj);` instead of `var {blah} = obj;`.

Comment: You shouldn't mutate global state anyway!